# Backfill - meaning

Tags: meaning, word-usage

Source: http://rt.com/news/155168-us-eu-sanctions-russia/

> But Europe has much to lose from imposing economic sanctions on Russia, and Obama said he sees how US-only sanctions won’t work.
>
> “If we, for example, say that we are not going to allow certain arms sales to Russia, but every European defense contractor **backfills** what we do, then it’s not very effective,” he said.

What does the verb **backfill** mean in this context?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What he means is if the US goes ahead with sanctions against Russia but Europe does not, the Europeans will just take the Russian contracts that the Americans refuse.

The purpose of an economic sanction is to create a "hole" in the target's economy, preventing them from obtaining a critical supply or resource. But sanctions don't work if someone else comes along and fills in that hole. That's the metaphor he's using: "backfill" is a construction related word for filling in a hole.